# Open source alternatives to twitter

Tags: untagged

What open source Twitter / Facebook alternatives exist for use in the workplace?

I see some pages for things like [EchoWaves](https://www.echowaves.com/), but I am looking for a list of options/thoughts.

Preferably Ruby based.

Comment: what problem does "twitter" or its clone solve for you and your colleagues?

Comment: It would provide a "passive" 2-way communication mechanism. People across the company can raise/discuss internal/related issues in a less direct/"in your face" mechanism than email

Comment: Salesforce.com added a twitter like feature called chatter to their sales platform, but it is not open source. It does show that there is interest for micro-blogging inside of a company. http://www.zdnet.com/photos/salesforcecoms-chatter-a-walkthrough/437137

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to install your own Twitter alternative I would take a look at [StatusNet](http://status.net/). That is the "open source microblogging platform" which among other things powers [identi.ca](http://identi.ca/).

Answer (score 2):

You could cover most your requirements between [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) (Jabber), [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_IRCds), a "[blog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Weblog_software)," mailing lists, and a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software).

Comment: Using chat rooms can actually do wonders to "passively" keep people in formed. Where I work we have an internal IRC server, and at least a lot of the Sysadmin work i coordinated in designated IRC channels. Even if you are just talking to a single other person, you still do it in the channel, giving others the chance to get a feel for what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You could just look for an application that posts status updates to all of your profiles at once, chances are that won't be blocked. I know they exist, but no names come to mind right away. I'll comment when they do

Answer (score 1):

If by open source, you mean that you can download and modify the source code.

[Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29) has Twitter-functionality on the personal wiki where you can update your status and follow other peoples' status.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/

It's not based on [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), but runs on a Java application server (Tomcat) with a database back end (Recommended is PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook style functionality, [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org) is pretty much drop-in and go.  [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) can be built into a pretty decent community-oriented site as well (there's a [fair-to-middling book on the topic](http://drupal.org/node/367131)), but that would require a fair amount of Drupal familiarity to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

Yammer could fill the need, though I don't believe you can install it locally. https://www.yammer.com/

Comment: LOL, it would seem ideal, and a few days ago our internal news site said that another part of our group was using Yammer and suggested we do too.. 2 days later it got "blocked", as not endorsed by "the board" :(